# Split String with regex and keep the delimiter

Tags: dart

I have following string:

```dart
final String text = "Hello, I'm Jone. I'm (1) **** USA. I'm (2) **********. This";
```

I wanted to split the string and get the following result:

```dart
[
"Hello, I'm Quang. I'm (1) ", 
"****", 
" USA. I'm (2) ", 
"**********",
". This"
]
```

`final re = RegExp(r'(?=\*)');`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

1. Split the text by sequences of asterisks and non-asterisks parts.
2. Use the RegExp to find matches and map them to their groups,
   effectively splitting the string as desired.

```
final String text = "Hello, I'm Jone. I'm (1) **** USA. I'm (2) **********. This";

final RegExp re = RegExp(r'(\*+|[^*]+)');

final List<String> parts = re.allMatches(text).map((match) => match.group(0)!).toList();

// Here the print is just an example. 
print(parts);
```

Comment: (Good answer! I'd remove the `(`..`)` from the RegExp, the code doesn't use the capture, and group 1 is always the same as group 0. It's also recommend to use `match[0]` instead of `match.group(0)`.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this one, I guess it can work

```
final String text = "Hello, I'm Jone. I'm (1) **** USA. I'm (2) **********. This";
final RegExp re = RegExp(r'(\*+)|([^*]+)');
final Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = re.allMatches(text);
final List<String> parts = matches.map((match) => match.group(0)!).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

What @yusof-khan said: Don't split, match. Every sequence of asterisks, and every sequence of non-asterisks, should together be the entire string.

If you *do* insist on splitting, if you have to pass a RegExp to some code that you didn't write, which uses `split`, I'd split on asterisk/non-asterisk *boundaries*, not on the asterisks themselves.
(Be certain what you want to use as separator, I'm using any seqeunce of asterisks, down to a single one. If you want at least three, or something, you should adapt the regexp.)

```dart
// Regexp matching *zero width* positions with a `*` before and a non-`*`
// after, or a non-`*` before and a `*` after.
final _asteriskSplitRE = RegExp(r"(?<=[*]{1})(?=[^*])|(?<=[^*])(?=[*]{1})");
List<String> asteriskSplit(String input) =>
    input.split(_asteriskSplitRE);
```

The `{1}` is unnecessary, but if you only want to consider, say, three `*`s as a separator, not less, then change `{1}` to `{3}` in both places, and it should work. If one `*` is enough, you can just remove the `{1}`.